# Flatten Spark DataFrame Sub Schema

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

Given a nested schema I want to **flatten a sub-struct** while maintaining the other schema structures. In this example I want to flatten the columns contained within product.spec so that I end up with `product.sid` & `product.desc`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
 
case class Spec(sid: Int, desc: String)
case class Prod(pid: String, spec: Spec)
 
val df = Seq(
  (101, "jenn", Seq(1, 2), Seq(Spec(1, "A"), Spec(2, "B")), Prod("X11", Spec(11, "X")), 1100.0),
  (202, "mike", Seq(3), Seq(Spec(3, "C")), Prod("Y22", Spec(22, "Y")), 2200.0)
).toDF("uid", "user", "ids", "specs", "product", "amount")

df.printSchema
>>>
root
 |-- uid: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- specs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- sid: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- spec: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sid: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- amount: double (nullable = false)
```

Desired new schema:

```
root
 |-- uid: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- specs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- sid: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- spec: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sid: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- amount: double (nullable = false)
```

Sadly the default SQL interface doesn't not allow this to be done easily because it takes the column names litrally.

```
//incorrect result
df.withColumn("product.sid", col("product.spec.sid")).withColumn("product.desc", col("product.spec.desc")).drop("product.spec.desc").drop("product.spec.sid").printSchema
>>
root
 |-- uid: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- specs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- sid: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- spec: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sid: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- amount: double (nullable = false)
 |-- product.sid: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- product.desc: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reconstruct the `product` struct column:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("product", struct("product.pid", "product.spec.sid", "product.spec.desc"))

df2.show
+---+----+------+----------------+------------+------+
|uid|user|   ids|           specs|     product|amount|
+---+----+------+----------------+------------+------+
|101|jenn|[1, 2]|[[1, A], [2, B]]|[X11, 11, X]|1100.0|
|202|mike|   [3]|        [[3, C]]|[Y22, 22, Y]|2200.0|
+---+----+------+----------------+------------+------+
```